# understanding node.js-module 'config' and default.json & production.json & my actual problem with a "Configuration property"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, node-config

https://github.com/node-config/node-config

Quote from github:

> Install in your app diectory, and edit the default config file:
>
> $ npm install config
>
> $ mkdir config
>
> $ vi config/default.json"

here the overview talks about how to install it and THEN creating the dir config.
but after installing via 'npm install config' there already was a folder "node_modules/config" created. how could it be installed without that folder anyhow and why do I need to create a foulder AFTER the instalation??

---

more important question: these files do **not** exist:

- config/default.json
- config/production.json

and somehow my node.js server isn't taking my post request correctly and the debugger stops here:

---

**M:...\Projekt22\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:182**

**throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
^**

**Error: Configuration property "sessionStorage.timeout" is not defined**

---

So I wonder now, if there is an issue with my config.js, with the "config/default.json" or "config/production.json"... that don't exist...

Can anyone explain all this to me?

---

This are the lines, where my code stops working:

```
var expirationTime = config.get("sessionStorage.timeout")

var expiresAT = issueAt + (expirationTime * 1000)
```

And this is the whole module of my program, where the crash happens:

```
var userService = require("../user/UserService")
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken") 
var config = require("config")
/* const logger = require("nodemon/lib/utils/log"); */


function createSessionToken(props, callback) {
    console.log("AuthenticationService: create Token");

    if (!props) {
        console.log("Error: have no json body")
        callback("JSON-Body missing", null, null)
        return
    }

    userService.findUserBy(props.userID, function (error, user) {

        if (user) {
            console.log("Found user, checking password...")

            user.comparePassword(props.password, function (err, isMatch) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log("Password is invalid")
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Password is correct. Create token.")

                    var issueAt = new Date().getTime()
                    var expirationTime = config.get("sessionStorage.timeout")
                    var expiresAT = issueAt + (expirationTime * 1000)
                    var privateKey = config.get("session.tokenKey")
                    let token = jwt.sign({ "user": user.userID }, privateKey, { expiresIn: expiresAT, algorithm: "HS256" })

                    console.log("Token created: " + token)

                    callback(null, token, user)
                }
            }
            )              
        }
        else {
            console.log("Session Services: Did not find user for user ID: " + props.userID)
            callback("Did not find user", null);
        }
    })
}

module.exports = {
    createSessionToken
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that using the `config` word will confuse you, so we need to agree on this:

1. I will use the word `config` to refer to the `config package`
2. I will use `setting` to refer to the config folder you make yourself. (by using `mkdir config`)

Now come to your questions:

1. `npm install config` registers the `config` package to your app. Without this, your app cannot use that config package, like when you use require('config'), it will report error
2. The `config` package itself reads your configuration from the `setting` folder, that's the reason you have to `mkdir config`
3. The `setting` folder above is not the same as in `node_modules/config`. The code of `config` package lives in node_modules. When you use `require('config')`, node will go and fetch the code from node_modules folder
4. Those 2 json files are created by you, see the instruction:

```js
vi config/default.json
vi config/production.json
```

`vi` is short for vim editor, it has a superpower where you don't need to create the file before editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're just confusing the destination folder you're supposed to be putting your JSON. That's it! :)

The `/config` folder needs to be in your project root, not `/node_modules/config` (that is where node actually places the config npm package, which is why the directory is created when you did `npm install config`).

To fix things just do this...

1. Create a file (in the root of your project) called `/config/default.json`
2. Put this in it:

```
{
  "sessionStorage": {
    "timeout": 100
  }
}
```

3. Then in your code...

```
// experationTime now equals "100" (or whatever your put in /config/default.json)! :)
var expirationTime = config.get("sessionStorage.timeout")
```

Presto!

The config npm can do all sorts of layering magic, so don't give up. it's one of the most powerful packages out there! :)